# Switch img src on slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using [Maximage 2](http://www.aaronvanderzwan.com/maximage/) plugin for my web site background slider but if my slider is at third image i want change that image with my logo src.

It's my slider

```
<div id="maximage">
            <img src="assets/img/slide-01.gif" class="img-responsive"/>
            <img src="assets/img/slide-02.gif" class="img-responsive" />
            <img src="assets/img/slide-03.gif" class="img-responsive" />
    </div>
```

It's my logo

```
<img id="logo" src="assets/img/logo.svg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
```

Comment: why are you not directly using 3rd images as your logo

Comment: There is no `events` section in documentation..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can invoke callback in maximage 'before' and 'after' transition happens!
Maximage has `cycleOptions` Object. According to official documentation,  [Here](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html) are all options you can pass with cycleOption object.
[image]

Here is [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jimishf/sLEyE/2180/).

In fiddle i'm changing Src of logo in 'after' callback, but you can do whatever you want to do in that function.
You can also use 'before' callback.

[Another Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jimishf/sLEyE/2181/)

Comment: code example for 2rd item please. thank you. i'm student.

Comment: Checkout fiddle. :)

Comment: If you are happy with solution, then please mark this answer as correct one.

Comment: Jimish. I have a problem. 3rd after i wan't not change src. so after 3rd change default src. how can i do it and When again in loop not working your solution.

Comment: Jimish. When loop Background image change but image src not change.i want change src but related image.

like this:
slide-01.gif with logo-green
slide-02.gif with logo-red
slide-03.gif with logo-default

thank you.